# Zend Framework 2 Best way to implement sessions

Tags: php, session, implementation, zend-framework2

I have a code like this:

```
        $sessionOptions = new SessionDbSavehandlerOptions();
        $sessionOptions->setDataColumn('data')
                       ->setIdColumn('id')
                       ->setModifiedColumn('modified')
                       ->setLifetimeColumn('lifetime')
                       ->setNameColumn('name');
        $application    = $event->getApplication();
        $serviceManager = $application->getServiceManager();
        $dbAdapter = $serviceManager->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
        $sessionTableGateway = new TableGateway('zf2_sessions', $dbAdapter);
        $sessionGateway = new DbTableGateway($sessionTableGateway, $sessionOptions);
        $config = $serviceManager->get('Configuration');
        $sessionConfig = new SessionConfig();
        $sessionConfig->setOptions($config['session']);
        $sessionManager = new SessionManager($sessionConfig);
        $sessionManager->setSaveHandler($sessionGateway);
        $sessionManager->start();
        Container::setDefaultManager($sessionManager);
```

works good but this code is in `onBootstrap()` method in `Module.php` file. Is there a better way (place?) to implement session? Controller plugins are for Controller, so what is for these?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suggestion would be to make this a dedicated, low level module. You can encapsulate the complete configuration and instantiation into a simple module which you can depend on for your further application.

It is quite the same as we handle our [mail](https://github.com/soflomo/mail), [logging](https://github.com/soflomo/log) and [cache](https://github.com/soflomo/cache) (though cache is not complete yet). In those cases we create services which we can inject in our application services. In your case, I would make it a listener (encapsuled in a dedicated class or not) where you initialize it in your `onBootstrap()` method.

A small example:

```
namespace MySession;

use Zend\Session\Container;

class Module
{
    public function onBootstrap($e)
    {
        $app = $e->getApplication();
        $sm  = $app->getServiceManager();

        $manager = $sm->get('session_manager');
        $manager->start();

        Container::setDefaultManager($manager);
    }

    public function getServiceConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
                'session_manager' => 'MySession\Service\SessionManagerFactory'
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

And you encapsulate the session manager's factory logic in a factory class:

```
namespace MySession\Service;

use Zend\ServiceManger\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

// Your imports further here

class SessionManagerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $sl)
    {
        $sessionOptions = new SessionDbSavehandlerOptions();
        $sessionOptions->setDataColumn('data')
                       ->setIdColumn('id')
                       ->setModifiedColumn('modified')
                       ->setLifetimeColumn('lifetime')
                       ->setNameColumn('name');
        $application    = $event->getApplication();
        $serviceManager = $application->getServiceManager();
        $dbAdapter = $serviceManager->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
        $sessionTableGateway = new TableGateway('zf2_sessions', $dbAdapter);
        $sessionGateway = new DbTableGateway($sessionTableGateway, $sessionOptions);
        $config = $serviceManager->get('Configuration');
        $sessionConfig = new SessionConfig();
        $sessionConfig->setOptions($config['session']);
        $sessionManager = new SessionManager($sessionConfig);
        $sessionManager->setSaveHandler($sessionGateway);

        return $sessionManager;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, everything is even better that before :) Thank you for advice.