# How to use zend framework SESSION globally in all modules with single time declaration?

Tags: php, session, zend-framework2

I am new in *Zend Framework 2* and I am learning about various *ZF2* modules.

I found many online links related to session handling in ZF2 like below:

**[using-sessions-in-zend-framework-2-part-1](http://www.masterzendframework.com/sessions/using-sessions-in-zend-framework-2-part-1)**

But in that tutorial they only focus on declaring a **session** class and variable in an individual **module**.

**How can I create a login module, set a session in there and use it in all other modules**?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to register a service that handles your sessions in your `service_manager`. You could call this service your `session_manager`. This is the proper *ZF2* way to get global access to services.

Such solutions can be found on StackOverflow like [for example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14025697/1697459).

Once you have registered a `session_manager` you can access it from everywhere using your `ServiceManager` instance like this:

```
$sessionManager = $serviceManager->get('session_manager');
```